# Anaconda/Spyder (Python 3.7) showing AttributeError: 'HTMLParserTreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'store_line_numbers'. Issue with Pandas?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to learn Web scraping and I am having issues with using Spyder on Anaconda. I can run this code on repl.it and python3.8 no problem but I keep getting the same error message on spyder which is "AttributeError: 'HTMLParserTreeBuilder' object has no attribute 'store_line_numbers'". I am very new to python programming but I have spent a lot of time trying to determine why I cannot run my code. I did see someone else's issue where they had something similar and I tried the solution of doing "conda install -c conda-forge beautifulsoup4" but I still have the same issue.

I have done conda install beautifulsoup4, requests, and pandas

From what I can tell it seems that there is an issue with pandas but I am not sure.

Any help would be much appreciated! I have attached all the code below!

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Helena, MT Weather
page = requests.get('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=46.5898&lon=-112.0206#.Xs8QUDpKjIU')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
week = soup.find(id='seven-day-forecast-body')

items = week.find_all(class_='tombstone-container')

period_names = [item.find(class_= 'period-name').get_text() for item in items]
short_descriptions = [item.find(class_= 'short-desc').get_text() for item in items]
temperatures = [item.find(class_= 'temp').get_text() for item in items]
#print(period_names)
#print(short_descriptions)
#print(temperatures)

weather_info = pd.DataFrame(
  {'period':period_names,
  'short_descriptions': short_descriptions,
  'temperatures': temperatures,
  })

print(weather_info)

weather_stuff.to_csv('weather.csv')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I just ran your code and it worked for me (spyder 4.1.2). I don't think it's pandas as it's a HTML error. Open your anaconda prompt and run 'conda update -all' and restart spyder once it's done. Also I think your final line should be weather_info.to_csv('weather.csv') as weather_stuff is not declared elsewhere.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the environment?

Comment: Thank you noblerthanoedipus. That did work. For whatever reason I did try that and it did not work but when I did it again it worked. Not sure what was going on but now everything works! I appreciate all the help so much!